# How solve error with sftp: Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer?

Tags: centos, sftp

I did install sftp on CentOS
and did add new group:

```
groupadd sftp
```

did create new user:

```
useradd -m sftp_user_1 -s /sbin/nologin -g sftp
```

did create password:

```
passwd sftp_user_1
```

did change owner:

```
chown root /home/sftp_user_1
```

did change rights:

```
chmod 750 /home/sftp_user_1
```

did change owner:

```
chown sftp_user_1:sftp /home/sftp_user_1
```

did check user and group:

```
id sftp_user_1

[root@centos-24 home]# id sftp_user_1
uid=1000(sftp_user_1) gid=1000(sftp) groups=1000(sftp)
```

did make changes in file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

did change to

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

did add in end of file

```
Match Group sftp
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ChrootDirectory /home/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

did restart service

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

did try to connect to sftp server and returned error:

```
[root@centos-24 home]# sftp sftp_user_1@localhost
sftp_user_1@localhost's password:
packet_write_wait: Connection to ::1 port 22: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

How solve this problem?

Comment: You've changed the owner of `/home/sftp_user_1` to `sftp_user_1` only two steps after you changed it to `root`.  Why did you set it to `root` in the first place?  If you're following a set of instructions you found somewhere, please include that in your question.

Comment: now did returned error: sftp_user_1@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: use: 'tail -f /var/log/secure /var/log/audit ' and run your sftp call to check if useful messages come there. (and maybe increas loglevel to verbose in sshd_config...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does ChrootDirectory and a user's home directory work together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542440/how-does-chrootdirectory-and-a-users-home-directory-work-together)

Answer (score 2):

In this step

```
chown root /home/sftp_user_1
```

I must change and group to sftp

```
chown root:sftp /home/sftp_user_1
```

because in file /etc/ssh/sshd_config exist

```
Match Group sftp
```

Comment: Why? `/home/sftp_user_1` has no other:r-x access? If you have r-x access why sftp fails?

Answer (score 2):

Your `sftp` client is reporting that the remote end just abruptly terminated the connection.

In situations like this, it would be best to *read the logs of the server side*: if the remote server did in fact terminate the connection, the server's logs should say so - and usually they'll also say **why** the server did so.

In this specific case, this is what I saw when reproducing the problem:

```
Sep 23 14:53:52 centos7 sshd[1800]: Accepted password for sftp_user_1 from ::1 port 52166 ssh2
Sep 23 14:53:52 centos7 sshd[1800]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user sftp_user_1 by (uid=0)
Sep 23 14:53:52 centos7 sshd[1800]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/sftp_user_1" [postauth]
Sep 23 14:53:52 centos7 sshd[1800]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftp_user_1
```

"**Bad ownership or modes for chroot directory `/home/sftp_user_1`.**" So `sshd` is unhappy about the permissions of the `ChrootDirectory`, which in your case is equal to the home directory of the chrooted user.

According to `sshd_config(5)` man page, the directory the `ChrootDirectory` configuration parameter refers to must be owned by root and not writeable by anyone else:

> ChrootDirectory
>
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication.  At session startup sshd(8) checks that **all components of the pathname** are **root-owned** directories which are **not writable by any other user or group**.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

In other words, **the ChrootDirectory must not be the user's home directory, but a directory at least one level above it.** This requirement is stricter than with older versions of `sshd`. It needs to be so, after someone discovered a new way to escape a chroot jail. The new requirement will make that escape method unusable.

See my answer in this other question for two possible solutions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542507/258991

Answer (score 0):

Always check the logs for any errors related to connectivity. Simple way to check it is by using the below commands.

```
grep -i username /var/log/auth.log
grep -i username /var/log/secure.log
```

In my case it was the home directory missing logs really helped me to identify the issue.